# scan-and-scroll doesn't work from Docker with a ElasticSearch cluster placed outside

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch

Currently I use Docker with an ElasticSearch cluster, which is placed outside the container.
From my docker I manage to create a mapping (so my ip it's good), and I manage to launch simple request in python language.

```
def getBodyOfRoot(self, id):
        res = self.es.get(index=self.ES_Index, doc_type=self.ES_Type, id=id)
        return res['_source']
```

this example works well in my host AND in Docker.

But when I launch my scan-and-scroll from Docker, I don't get a response, but from my native OS, I get a response.

If you have already met this problem, how did you manage to solve it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may i know how you are accessing the cluster? i mean the code sample

Comment: What's your scan and scroll code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to issue the scan and scroll from your Docker container using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/):

```
curl -XGET http://elastic-search-host:9200/my_index/_search?scroll=1m&search_type=scan&size=10 -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "elasticsearch"
        }
    }
}
'
```